# Call several "measure" operations synchronously

Tags: react-native, measure

I have to measure several values with a help of `measure()` function.
Because it is async operation, I can only write:

```
this.refContainerView.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
  const containerViewHeight = height

  this.refCommentList.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
    const commentListOffset = pageY
    const commentListHeight = height

  // do something

  })
})
```

and if needed to measure more components, it looks like a callback hell.
Is it possible to write code synchronously, e.g. with help of `await` or other, e.g.:

```
const contaierView = this.refContainerView.measure()
const commentList = this.refCommentList.measure()

// and then do something with 
contaierView {x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY}
commentList  {x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY}
```

Answer (score 5):

I found the kind of solution.
`measure()` is not a promise, but has function with callback:

```
measureComponent = component => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    component.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
      resolve({ x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY })
    })
  })
}

onDoSomething = async () => {
  const [containerView, commentList] = await Promise.all([
    this.measureComponent(this.refContainerView),
    this.measureComponent(this.refCommentList),
  ])

  // do here with containerView and commentList measures   
  }
}
```